# Elementary set questions problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In an exam,there are 150 students. 40 passed in paper A & B.40 passed in
>   paper B & C. 30 passed in paper A & C and 10 passed in all three.How many
>   students passed in paper B only?
>   and also
>
> If no student failed find the number of student who passed in exactly one paper.

Can we determine the answer whereas individual value is not given.

Comment: Make a Venn diagram, plug the numbers and apply the conditions.

Comment: I have drawn the Ven diagram but confused to get the individual value bcz There are not any value given for only A and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach:**

Draw a Venn Diagram depicting the overlaps and relationships $|A\cap B| = 40,\;$ $\;|B \cap C |= 40,\;$  $\;|A\cap C| = 30,\;$ and the intersection $\;|A\cap B \cap C| = 10$.

The image **on the right, below,** depicts your situation.

[image]

Fill in the known number of students in each region.

- You will not be able to determine, from the given information, the precise number who passed in *only* $B$.
- But you will be able to determine the number of students, out of
  $150$, who must have **passed in only one paper,** provided no student
  failed in every paper.

Comment: Phew, I was hoping the first part wasn't possible.

Comment: @amWhy, so the fisrst part is not possible to answer? 

Answer of 2nd part will be : 150-(40+40+30-10) =50 ?

Comment: The first part is impossible to answer. The second question is $150 - (40 - 10) - (40 - 10) - (30 - 10) -10 = 60$. Recall that $(A\cap B)$ and $(A\cap B\cap C)$ overlap by 10. Ditto for $B\cap C$ and $A\cap C$ *each* overlapping with $(A\cap B \cap C)$ by 10 each.

Comment: Like your pie graphs